# custom rules parser

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a set of *masks*.

The masks look like this

> '09{2,9}n(6)'
>   //read as 09
>   //[a number between 2 and 9]
>   //[a random number][repeat expression 6 times]
>
> '029n(7,10)'
>   //read as 029
>   //[a random number][repeat expression between 7 and 10 times]
>
> '029n(2,5){8,15}(7,10)n'
>   //read as 029
>   //[a random number][repeat expression between 2 and 5 times]
>   //[a random number between 8 and 15][repeat expression between 7 and 10 times]
>   //[a random number]
>
> as an example expession 3 would work out as
>   '029n(4){4,9}(7)n'
>   '029nnnn{4,9}{4,9}{4,9}{4,9}{4,9}{4,9}{4,9}n
>   '029nnnn{5}{9}{4}{8}{5}{9}{9}n
>   '029nnnn5948599n'
>   '029023559485999'

I need to write a parser in javascript that can **generate a string** based on those rules.
Note that this is **not validation**, it is string generation.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Im thinking first step would would do find all `(1,10)//(5)`'s and expand the expression behind them x amount of times?

Comment: next step would be to find all `{1,8}`'s and replace them with the number between 1 and 8?

Comment: and finally replace all `n`'s with a random number

Comment: now I just need to work out how to do that...

Comment: @Hailwood - in example 3, what is the part that gets repeated - is it only the expression preceding immediately or everything before it?

Comment: only the expression immediately preceding it.

Comment: You might want to use a [parser generator](http://pegjs.majda.cz/online).

Comment: @Austin Tayor, Do you have experience with peg? are you able to provide me with some help? [eg the rule that would take (2,5) and repeat the previous expression between 2 and 5 times]?

Comment: note that the expression formats above are able to be changed if need be...

Comment: @Hailwood - how would an expression like `n(2, 5)(3)` work or is this an invalid expression? if it is valid, does it first expand n anywhere between 2 and 5 times, let's say `"nnnn"` then takes the last expression and repeat it thrice to make `"nnnnnnn"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying out a custom parser. Use as,

```
var generator = new PatternGenerator('09{2,9}n(6)');
generator.generate(); // 096555555
generator.generate(); // 095000000
```

Checkout this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/35N8h/).

And the constructor function,

```
function PatternGenerator(pattern) {
    var tokens = null;

    this.generate = function() {
        var stack = [];
        tokens = pattern.split('');

        // Read each token and add
        while (tokens.length) {
            var token = lookahead();
            if (isDigit(token)) {
                stack.push(consumeNumber());
            }
            else if (token == "n") {
                stack.push(consumeVariableNumber());
            }
            else if (token == "(") {
                var topObject = stack.pop();
                stack.push(consumeRepetition(topObject));
            }
            else if (token == "{") {
                stack.push(consumeVariableRangeNumber());
            }
            else {
                throw new Error("Invalid input");
            }
        }
        return stack.join('');
    }

    // [0-9]+
    function consumeNumber() {
        var number = "";
        while (isDigit(lookahead())) {
            number += consume();
        }
        return number;
    }

    // "n"
    function VariableNumber() {
        var number = generateRandomNumber();

        this.toString = function() {
            return Number(number);
        };
    }

    function consumeVariableNumber() {
        consume();
        return new VariableNumber();
    }

    // {x, y}
    function VariableRangeNumber(start, end) {
        var number = generateRandomNumberBetween(start, end);

        this.toString = function() {
            return Number(number);
        };
    }

    function consumeVariableRangeNumber() {
        consume(); // {
        var firstNumber = consumeNumber();
        consume(); // ,
        var secondNumber = consumeNumber();
        consume(); // }
        return new VariableRangeNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }

    // <expression>(x)
    function Repeat(object, times) {
        this.toString = function() {
            var string = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
                string += object;
            }
            return string;
        };
    }

    // <expression>(x, y)
    function RepeatWithRange(object, start, end) {
        var times = generateRandomNumberBetween(start, end);

        this.toString = function() {
            return new Repeat(object, times).toString();
        };
    }

    function consumeRepetition(object) {
        consume(); // (
        var firstNumber, secondNumber;
        var firstNumber = consumeNumber();
        if (lookahead() == ",") {
            consume(); // ,
            secondNumber = consumeNumber();
        }
        consume(); // )

        if (typeof secondNumber == 'undefined') {
            return new Repeat(objectToRepeat, firstNumber);
        }
        else {
            return new RepeatWithRange(object, firstNumber, secondNumber);
        }
    }

    // Helpers to generate random integers
    function generateRandomNumber() {
        var MAX = Math.pow(2, 52);
        return generateRandomNumberBetween(0, MAX);
    }

    function generateRandomNumberBetween(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    function lookahead() {
        return tokens[0];
    }

    function consume() {
        return tokens.shift();
    }

    function isDigit(character) {
        return /\d/.test(character);
    }
}
```